# respsonse Handling problem in ios, alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, networking, alamofire

I try to make an API call with alamofire. when I print `response.value` like this `print(response.value ?? "")`  I get correct text in Xcode console, but I get an error  this line  `comletionHanlder(response.value as! [Order])`.

error message is `Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryI' (0x7f81db0f3070) to 'AppName.Order' (0x10db3fb80)`

```
static func getOrders( comletionHanlder: @escaping ([Order]) -> Void){
    let headers : HTTPHeaders = ["Authorization" : "Bearer \(User.current!.accessToken)",
                "Lang"          : "KA"]

    let urlStr = Constants.Api.baseUrl + Constants.Api.Routes.api + Constants.Api.Routes.doctorBooking + Constants.Api.Routes.getBookings

    AF.request(urlStr,
               method: .post,
               encoding: JSONEncoding.default,
               headers: headers).responseJSON{ response in

               if response.response?.statusCode == 400 {
                    comletionHanlder([])
                } else {
                if response.response?.statusCode == 200 {
                    print(response.value ?? "")
                    comletionHanlder(response.value as! [Order])
                }
          }
    }
```

;

```
struct Order: Codable {
    let title: String
    let details: String
    let BookingId: Int
}
```

when I print `response.value`, I got this message

```
(
    {
      title = "title"
      details = "details"
      BookingId = 10002
     },
     {
      title = "title1"
      details = "details1"
      BookingId = 10003
     }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated on the error message, casting the `response.value` to `Order` won't work. You should use the `JSONDecodable` class to decode the response to the desired list of orders like this:

```
guard let responseData = response.data else { /* do something */ }    
do {
    let orders = try JSONDecoder().decode([Order].self, from: responseData)
    debugPrint(orders)
} catch {
    // handle the error
}
```

Comment: I change my code but also I get an error `keyNotFound(CodingKeys(stringValue: "title", intValue: nil), Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [_JSONKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0)], debugDescription: "No value associated with key CodingKeys(stringValue: \"title\", intValue: nil) (\"title\").", underlyingError: nil))`

Comment: I added in my `Order` struct codingKeys like this

`enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { ...}`

Comment: @RezoJoglidze it seems the response has some null values. Try changing some of the `Order` properties to optionals. ex: `struct Order: Codable {
    let title: String?
    let details: String?
    let BookingId: Int?
    
    public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let values = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        title = try? values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .title)
        details = try? values.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .details)
        BookingId = try? values.decodeIfPresent(Int.self, forKey: .BookingId)
    }
}
`

Comment: I change everything like your last answer. in **do**, I write this line `print (orders)`.

Comment: I ger orders like this, every field is nil 

`[AppName.Order(title: nil,  details: nil,BookingId: nil)]`

Comment: but if I print `response.value`, Every field is filled with some information/

Comment: thats all, I think, that I have problem in Json decodable